# How do I handle the existing screws when replacing flashing on a metal roof?

Tags: roofing, flashing

Just had our on-demand water heater replaced. A few days later, I noticed rain leaking around the vent pipe in the attic. The vent pipe has flashing installed on the metal roof, similar to the pic below. It looks like there's a small tear where it seals to the pipe and in general just looks like it's deteriorated a bit. I'd like to replace it with a similar flashing but I'm not sure how to handle all of the screws that were installed around the existing flashing. If I back those out, what must I do to ensure no leaking around them when they are removed? How do I make sure I don't reuse a hole by accident or insert a new screw too close to an existing hole and cause a tear in the metal roof?

[image]

Comment: Why not plan on reusing _all_ the holes in the metal roof instead of making a whole new set of them?

Comment: I'm not sure I could screw through the new flashing and hit every existing screw hole.

Comment: Maybe include a pic of the existing install. Someone might see a better way of fixing it that won't involve new holes...

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully the last guy used #10 roofing screws. Use #12 roofing screws for your installation. Butyl tape makes a nice gasket material instead of (or in addition to) sealant. Leave an unsealed couple inches at the low point so that any water that infiltrates can drain.

Answer (score 0):

[You need screws with neoprene washers](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Everbilt-14-x-1-in-Self-Drilling-Screw-with-Neoprene-Washer-1-lb-Box-62-Piece-116044/205142736).

[image: Metal rood screws with neoprene washers]

If you need to make new holes, put one of these screws in the old holes too, to seal them up. Additionally, I'd consider some [Henry's](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Henry-204-Plastic-Roof-Cement-0-90-gal-HE204142/100080447), which does come in white too, but maybe under a different name. Replace the flashing and parts as needed, fill all old holes with a screw and washer, then put a generous coat of Henry's on the whole area.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. So new screws in the existing holes, sealant over them, then replace the flashing.

Comment: @gnomer No, replace flashing first. 1) Get all the new parts into place, 2) screw them down, 3) apply sealant.

Comment: I'm not a big fan of the "generous coat of goo" approach. It looks like poo and can obscure actual problems. Seal the old holes. Install. Seal the new holes.

Comment: @isherwood Except the OP says it is leaking... I turn to the goo when it's leaking. I've wasted too many hours on roofs with a leak, moving this, shifting that, when these days I just slap some goo around the flashing. Yeah, you *see* it, but really only when you're looking for it. You'll forget it's there and probably never see it again. Unless it really stands out, which can be the case on occasion.